# Excel VBA - Erro em tempo de execução '13': Tipos Incompatíveis

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou recebendo o Erro '13' Tipos incompatíveis, na Linha do primeiro If:

```
Count = 0
For x = 1 To LastRow Step 1
    If Cells(x, 8).Value = "Materiais" Or Cells(x, 8).Value = "Imobilizado" Then
        If Cells(x, 11).Value = "NÃO CATALOGO" Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    End If
Next x
```

Alguém saberia dizer aonde está o problema?

Comment: Tente usar `CStr(Cells(x, 8).Value)` para converter a variável para String.

Comment: Outra pergunta: A sua pasta de trabalho possui várias planilhas? As vezes o código executado está pegando os valores de outra planilha e não na desejada.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque .Text no lugar de .Value nos testes feitos com if.

```
Count = 0
For x = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(x, 8).Text = "Materiais" Or Cells(x, 8).Text = "Imobilizado" Then
        If Cells(x, 11).Text= "NÃO CATALOGO" Then Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next x
```

Outra coisa é que esse código depende de estar com a sheet desejada ativa.
Caso não queira que ela tenha que estar ativa, use uma variável para referenciá-la.
Ex.

```
    set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")

    Count = 0
    For x = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(x, 8).Text = "Materiais" Or ws.Cells(x, 8).Text = "Imobilizado" Then
            If ws.Cells(x, 11).Text= "NÃO CATALOGO" Then Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz testes com seu código e nada de anormal, segue o que fiz. Aparentemente está funcionando corretamente. Já tentou rever a lógica, qual resultado esperado?

**Entradas**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**

```
Sub tst()
    LastRow = 18
    Count = 0
    For x = 1 To LastRow Step 1
        If Cells(x, 8).Value = "Materiais" Or Cells(x, 8).Value = "Imobilizado" Then
            Debug.Print Cells(x, 8).Value & vbTab & " - " & vbTab & Count
            If Cells(x, 11).Value = "NÃO CATALOGO" Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

**Resultados:**

```
Materiais    -  0
Materiais    -  0
Imobilizado  -  0
Materiais    -  0
Materiais    -  1
Materiais    -  1
Imobilizado  -  1
Materiais    -  1
Materiais    -  2
Imobilizado  -  2
Materiais    -  2
Materiais    -  3
Imobilizado  -  3
Imobilizado  -  3
Imobilizado  -  3
Imobilizado  -  3
Imobilizado  -  4
Imobilizado  -  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tenho um conhecimento muito limitado de VBA, mas acredito que o problema seja incompatibilidade entre as variáveis. Tive um problema similar e para resolvê-lo apenas tive que retirar as aspas das variáveis dentro If. Desculpem se estou falando bobagem, é por desconhecer mesmo, abraço.

Answer (score -2):

Amigo vou dar um exemplo que aconteceu comigo. Eu também tive esse mesmo problema quando escrevia um código. Eu tinha um string que continha uma lista de materiais e usei a função split para, a partir dessa string, criar várias substrings e jogá-las num vetor.

```
                material = DAD_CP.Cells(cont, 8).Value 'Pega a lista_material de materiais e joga na string material
            If (material <> "") Then

                lista_material = Split(material, Chr(10)) 'Coloca todos os materiais no Array lista_material
                'lista_material(UBound(lista_material) + 1) = Mid(material, (InStr(InStr(1, Chr(10), material) + 1, Chr(10), material) + 1), Len(material)) ' Pega o último item da lista_material de materiais
            End If
```

Eu tinha declarado lista_material e lista_obra na mesma linha, e sempre dava esse erro de Tipos Incompatíveis. O que me dava raiva é que os tipos eram compatíveis sim pois a variável material é uma string e a variável lista_material() era um vetor do tipo string. Mas aí eu decidi exibir a janela de variáveis enquanto eu depurava o código e acabei descobrindo que desgraçada não estava como um vetor de string e sim um vetor tipo Variant, mesmo que no código estivesse esplicitamente declarada como String. Dá pra acreditar? Ai eu declarei ela como String só que em uma linha separada e isolada, e adivinha só? Deu certo! Conclusão: Parece que o VBA não reconhece quando vc declara dois vetores do Tipo string na mesma linha pois lista_obra estava como vetor de string mas lista material não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja acima que quando eu declaro os dois vetores na mesma linha uma fica como string e a outra fica como Variant. Mas veja agora que quando eu declaro ambas separadamente ela ficam com seus tipos originais. Acho que isso deves ser algum bug do VBA Excel. Mas concluindo o raciocínio, quando ocorrer esse erro chato de tipos incompatíveis tente declarar as variáveis separadamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Favor não postar [código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/75104).